# FileEdit in Chef giving error in Windows

Tags: chef-infra

I am trying to replace a string of a xml file. Tried following recipe. Didn't work

```
ruby_block 'replace_file' do
  block do
    f= Chef::Util::File_Edit.new('C:\Chef_File_Edit\server.xml')
    f.search_file_replace(8081,8080)
    f.write_file
   end
 end
```

My Moto is to replace 8081 with 8080. What is wrong in above recipe?

Comment: Because it is `Chef::Util::FileEdit`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use strings instead of integers, `f.search_file_replace('8081', '8080')`. It is also worth noting that use of FileEdit is highly, **highly** not recommended. It leads to very brittle systems. Using a `template` or `cookbook_file` resource to control your `server.xml` file is going to be a better solution.

Comment: Thanks. I will try to implement it with cookbook_file resource as well. 
I got this error...
FATAL: NameError: ruby_block[replace_file] (file_edit::default line 10) had an error: NameErro
r: uninitialized constant Chef::Util::File_Edit
ERROR: Failed to execute command on 10.106.69.76 return code 1

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, it worked. I did two mistakes. This is the correct recipe.

```
ruby_block 'replace_file' do
  block do
    f= Chef::Util::FileEdit.new('C:\Chef_File_Edit\server.xml')
    f.search_file_replace('8081','8080')
    f.write_file
  end
end
```